# Why does asp:Textbox sometimes add "text" to the CSS class in the rendered html?

Tags: asp.net, css

This markup:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" CssClass="s175" runat="server" MaxLength="30" placeholder="Street"></asp:TextBox>`

is rendered as:

`<input name="ctl00$LeftColumnContent$txtAddress" type="text" maxlength="30" id="LeftColumnContent_txtAddress" class="s175 text" placeholder="Street">`

But on another project, this markup: (exactly the same)

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" CssClass="s175" runat="server" MaxLength="30" placeholder="Street"></asp:TextBox>`

causes this to happen:

`<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtAddress" type="text" maxlength="30" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAddress" class="s175" placeholder="Street">`

Why is the "text" class not getting applied? It's `class="s175"` vs `class="s175 text"`.

Comment: Is there a default skin applied to textboxes in this project?

Comment: What do you mean by default skin? As far as I know, there is only css being used to style it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting added from javascript. I think it's this:

jquery.uniform.js

```
function doInput(elem){
  $el = $(elem);
  $el.addClass($el.attr("type"));
  storeElement(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply skins to controls in asp.net, http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ykzx33wh.aspx , if there is a default skin in this particular project it might explain why the class is being added. Check for a .skin file in the project.

Comment: I searched for .skin files, none found. There is an App_Themes folder but it only has .css in it.